# How to RENAME struct/array nested columns using ALTER TABLE in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Suppose we have the following table in BigQuery:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_dataset.sample_table (
  id               INT
  ,struct_geo      STRUCT
  <
    country        STRING
    ,state         STRING
    ,city          STRING
  >
  ,array_info       ARRAY
  <
    STRUCT<
      key          STRING
      ,value       STRING
    >
  >
);
```

I want to rename the columns inside the `STRUCT` and the `ARRAY` using an `ALTER TABLE` command. It's possible to follow the Google documentation [available here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_name) for normal columns ("non-nested" columns) i:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_dataset.sample_table
RENAME COLUMN id TO str_id
```

But when I try to run the same command for nested columns I got errors from BigQuery.
Running the command for a column inside a `STRUCT` gives me the following message:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_dataset.sample_table
RENAME COLUMN `struct_geo.country` TO `struct_geo.str_country`
```

Error: `ALTER TABLE RENAME COLUMN not found: struct_geo.country`.

The exact same message appears when I run the same statement, but targeting a column inside an `ARRAY`:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_dataset.sample_table
RENAME COLUMN `array_info.str_key` TO `array_info.str_key`
```

Error: `ALTER TABLE RENAME COLUMN not found: array_info.str_key`

I got stuck since the BigQuery documentation about nested columns ([available here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#modify_nested_and_repeated_columns)) lacks examples of `ALTER TABLE` statements and refers directly to the default documentation for non-nested columns.

I understand that I can rename the columns by simply creating a new table using a `CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT ...` and then passing the new column names as aliases, but this would run a query over the whole table, which I'd rather avoid since my original table weighs way over 10TB...

Thanks in advance for any tips or solutions!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not supported yet.   *You cannot use this statement to rename the following: Subfields, such as nested columns in a STRUCT*

visit https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#details_15

Comment: This feature is currently not available in BigQuery. If you want this feature in BigQuery, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).